# Weird Angular2 Model Binding Issue

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm running into a place where the model binding on Angular2 is not binding as I expect, and I'm having problems determining where I went awry.

I have an array of objects as follows:

```js
commands = [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "command": "!first",
        "action": "This is the first command. You found it!",
        "reply": false
    },
    {
       "id": 5,
        "command": "!hi",
        "action": "Hello, how are you today?",
        "reply": true
    },
    ...
];
```

The view template is as follows (clipped for brevity, only showing tags with relevant Angular2 info):

```html
<form #commandForm="ngForm">
    <tr *ngFor="#cmd of commands">
        <td *ngIf=" ! isEditingCommand(cmd)">{{ cmd.command }}</td>
        <td *ngIf="isEditingCommand(cmd)">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="!command" required [(ngModel)]="cmd.command" (ngModelChange)="cmd.command=cleanCommand($event)" ngControl="cmd" #cmd="ngForm">
        </td>
        <td *ngIf=" ! isEditingCommand(cmd)">{{ cmd.action }}</td>
        <td *ngIf="isEditingCommand(cmd)">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="Text to display." required [(ngModel)]="cmd.action" ngControl="action" #action="ngForm"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

When `isEditingCommand(cmd) === false`, rows show up as follows:

[image: State when not editing the command]

When `isEditingCommand(cmd) === true`, this is what I get:

[image: State when editing the command]

I have changed both `cmd` and `cmd.command` to various names, in case `command` is a reserved word for Angular2, to no avail. When I put `{{ cmd | json }}` in the view, I receive this exception:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in [
                {{ cmd | json }}
             in CommandComponent@24:199]
```

I am unable to determine how this could have a circular structure, unfortunately. Even going through the Chrome Inspector I am not finding a place where it might be circular.

[image: locals from Chrome Inspector]

To assist, here are the functions that are defined in the view (TypeScript is giving me problems; I will refactor into it later):

```js
CommandComponent.prototype.cleanCommand = function (value) {
    value = value.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, '');
    if (0 >= value.indexOf('!') && '!' !== value.substr(0, 1)) {
        value = '!' + value;
    }

    return value;
};
CommandComponent.prototype.isEditingCommand = function (command) {
    if (null === this.currentCommand) {
        return false;
    }

    return this.editFormActive && this.currentCommand.id === command.id;
};
// These are not used by the template shown, but they set values used in the functions.
CommandComponent.prototype.editCommand = function (command) {
    this.editFormActive = true;
    this.currentCommand = command;
};
CommandComponent.prototype.cancelEditCommand = function () {
    this.editFormActive = false;
    this.currentCommand = null;
};
```

Environment:

- Angular 2.0.0-beta.13
- RxJS 5.0.0-beta.2
- Zone.js 0.6.8

What did I do incorrectly? Let me know if more info is needed, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your issue correctly. But, I only see one problem that could cause some binding issues.

In this line:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="!command" required [(ngModel)]="cmd.command" (ngModelChange)="cmd.command=cleanCommand($event)" ngControl="cmd" #cmd="ngForm">
```

You redefined the local variable `cmd`. The first one, in the `*ngFor="#cmd of commands"`. The other one `#cmd="ngForm"`. So, the binding to `cmd.command` will be to `cmd` the `ngForm` not the `#cmd of commands`. In other words, You have added a new property `command` to `ngForm`.

This will explain the circular reference issue because `ngForm` is of type `NgFormName` which has a `_parent` reference.

Comment: I... wow. Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. That would definitely cause a potential problem. And it most definitely fixed things. Thank you!